# Relation between Continuity and Uniform Continuity

Tags: metric-spaces

Can we define a particular metric ( except for discrete metric ) on any given set in which continuity implies uniform continuity ?

Thanks for any help .

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused due to my editting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All compact metric spaces, since a continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: It feels as if the converse holds: If $X$ is a metric space with no isolated points and every continuous $f:X\to\mathbb RR$ is uniformly continuous, then $X$ is compact. Is that true?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I do not know. In any case I think $X$ should be complete.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen [This paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689666?seq=1) gives a positive answer to the question.

Comment: @Julian I am only getting the first page of the paper.Can you please give me the link to the full paper?

Comment: @Ricky I could get the whole paper. May be my institution has full access.

Answer (score 3):

In all compact metric spaces continuity and uniform continuity is equivalent.